# groupby output - not all groups are the same type?

Tags: pandas

(Apologies for all these simpleminded questions. Getting started with pandas is driving me up a wall.)

Given this short script:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse

frame = pd.DataFrame({'value': range(9)},
                      index=[dtparse("2014-03-14T02:30"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-14T14:45"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-14T16:45"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-15T02:30"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-15T14:45"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-15T16:45"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-16T02:30"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-16T14:45"),
                        dtparse("2014-03-16T16:45")])

grouped = frame.groupby(lambda x: x.date())

def group_filter(x):
    print ">>", type(x)
    return True

print grouped.filter(group_filter)
```

Can someone please explain this output?

```
>> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Why are the arguments passed to group_filter not all of the same type, and why does it appear there are four groups? (Printing x inside group_filter suggests that the group associated with 2014-03-14 is processed twice.) I grouped by date(). There should only be three groups, as this shows:

```
for key, grp in grouped:
    print key, type(grp)
    print grp
```

yields this:

```
2014-03-14 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
                     value
2014-03-14 02:30:00      0
2014-03-14 14:45:00      1
2014-03-14 16:45:00      2
2014-03-15 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
                     value
2014-03-15 02:30:00      3
2014-03-15 14:45:00      4
2014-03-15 16:45:00      5
2014-03-16 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
                     value
2014-03-16 02:30:00      6
2014-03-16 14:45:00      7
2014-03-16 16:45:00      8
```

I'm quite confused at this point.

Comment: see the note: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/groupby.html#flexible-apply. It is trying to figure out if it can use a fast path for computation or not.

Comment: This could prove problematic for me, as I want to extract a single row from each group matching a complex condition. Is there a way to tell pandas, "don't do that!"?

Comment: It doesn't affect you as its not visible to you. This tests whether you are mutating the input in the apply or not. Just use ``apply`` or iterate over the groups.

Comment: Hmmm... It would certainly seem to be visible to me if I use filter().

Comment: your use of ``filter`` is a pass-thru. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. have a look at the docs and usage. http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/groupby.html#filtration